# how to give external link from homepage to another page using bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress

how to give link one page to another page vertical tab using bootstrap.
External link page:

```
<div class="tt-service-info"><a class="tt-service-title c-h5" href="http://jsrgraphics.com/our-products#finishing">FINISHING EQUIPMENT</a></div>
```

Destination page:

```
<li class="tt-nav-tab-item"><a href="#finishing" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">FINISHING EQUIPMENT</a></li>
```

Tab content:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane text-style active" id="finishing">
  <h3 class="uppercase yes_border">1 Color Machine </h3>
       <p>
         <?php echo do_shortcode('[featured_product_categories cats="220" per_cat="6" columns="4"]') ?>  
       </p>   
</div>
```

Note: I want open particular tab, please help out here

Comment: Are you asking how to open a link in a new tab?

Comment: Your question looks simple but you have to rephrase it because it is not clear

Comment: For Example: I have home page in my website called http://jsrgraphics.com/, in that page(Products section) i have given href links, it redirects to another page our products page http://jsrgraphics.com/our-products/. in this page i have vertical tabs. these are in bootstrap. when click on home page it redirects to product page and open related tab.